# Interrupt javafx Service

Tags: javafx-8

I have implemented a javafx Service which is running fine. Problem is the task dont stop when i press a cancel button from UI. I have posted the code for the service i implemented.

```
cancel.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
        if(parsing.isRunning())
            parsing.cancel();
    });    



Service<Void> parsing = new Service() {

    private Task task;

    @Override
    protected Task<Void> createTask() {
        task = new Task<Void>() {
            @Override
            public Void call() throws InterruptedException {
                try {
                    for (int page = start; page <= end; page++) {
                        System.out.println("Scanning page."+page);
                        ...
                    }
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    System.out.println(ex);
                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void succeeded() {
                super.succeeded();
                System.out.println("Scanning completed.");
            }

            @Override 
            protected void failed() {
                 super.failed();
                 System.out.println("Scanning failed.");
            }

            @Override 
            protected void running() {
                 super.running();
                 System.out.println("Scanning started.");
            }

            @Override 
            protected void cancelled() {
                 super.cancelled();
                 System.out.println("Scanning cancelled.");
            }
        };
        return task;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean cancel() {
        if (task != null)
            return task.cancel(true);
        else
            return false;
    }
};
```

What am i doing wrong here? Any help is well appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Your `call()` method needs to check for the cancelled state. From the [documentation for `Task`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html):

> In Java there is no reliable way to "kill" a thread in process.
>   However, when cancel is called on a Task, it is important that the
>   Task stop processing. A "run-away" Task might continue processing and
>   updating the message, text, and progress properties even after the
>   Task has been cancelled! In Java, cancelling a Task is a cooperative
>   endeavor. The user of the Task will request that it be cancelled, and
>   the author of the Task must check whether is has been cancelled within
>   the body of the call method. There are two ways this can be done.
>   First, the Task author may check the isCancelled method, inherited
>   from FutureTask, to see whether the Task has been cancelled. Second,
>   if the Task implementation makes use of any blocking calls (such as
>   NIO InterruptibleChannels or Thread.sleep) and the task is cancelled
>   while in such a blocking call, an InterruptedException is thrown. Task
>   implementations which have blocking calls should recognize that an
>   interrupted thread may be the signal for a cancelled task and should
>   double check the isCancelled method to ensure that the
>   InterruptedException was thrown due to the cancellation of the Task.

Since you don't appear to have any blocking calls in the `call` method, you need to do something like:

```
    @Override
    public Void call() throws InterruptedException {
        try {
            for (int page = start; page <= end; page++) {

                if (isCancelled()) {
                    return null ;
                }

                System.out.println("Scanning page."+page);
                ...
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

and if you have nested loops, you might want to check for cancellation more frequently.